# Is atomic property thread safe in ObjC++

Tags: c++, objective-c, multithreading, thread-safety

It is said that properties using "atomic" are thread-safe in ObjC, but I wonder if it is still that way in ObjC++ with pthread.

Comment: @Golazo [Objective-C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C.2B.2B), a blend of Objective-C and C++.

Comment: @Angew Very interesting. What compiler knows both C++ and Objective C? I work on Windows, to mix C++ and C#, we use C++ CLI. What is used to mix ObjC and C++?

Comment: @Golazo As per the Wikipedia link I provided, GCC and Clang.

Comment: @Angew sorry, phone acting weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: No, it is *not* said that "atomicity" is thread-safety neither in general nor for declared properties, neither in Objective-C nor in C++. Atomicity means that no getter or setter (it is on object level, so even accessors of other properties) run simultaneously. But it says nothing of what happens immediately after setting or getting a value. To have thread-safety you have to do more. (Therefore atomicity of declared properties are akin of meaningless.) In the past atomic/nonatomic had more to do with memory management. This became less important by far since we have ARC.

After this, it is probably less important to answer to your Q: It is not documented, but has been documented a bit more in past. Apple said that they used an object level lock. Since even very simple `NSLock` uses pthreads internally – that's documented –, I assume that they work, if you created the threads with pthread.

---

A little sample:

```
@interface Person
@property NSString *fristName;
@property NSString *lastName;
@end

@implementation Person
@end
```

Control flow 1:

```
person.firstName = @"Chris";
person.lastName = @"Kienle";
```

Control flow 2:

```
person.firstName = @"Amin";
person.lastName = @"Negm";
…
NSString *combined = [NSString @"%@ %@", person.firstName, person.lastName];
```

Possible result with perfect atomic and thread-safe accessors:

```
Christian Negm
```

Comment: Ok, so in short, I will have to use explicit locking to make properties thread safe with pthread, correct?

Comment: In short, you have to use a known technology to make your code thread-safe. Thread-safety is neither a problem on property level nor solvable on property level. Added a example.